# My English homepage will not update

Tags: pages

I'm running an Indonesian foodblog and one page doesn't update anymore: my English homepage. All the other pages are doing fine, but just one will not update all of a sudden. I've checked all my plugins, but nothing seems to resolve it.

This is the page: https://pisangsusu.com/en/

Can somebody help me? Warm regards, Pauline

Comment: "Doesn't update" - what does it mean?

Comment: It seems fine for me. What are you expecting and what did you actually get?

Comment: Thanks I've solved the problem. Only one page of my complete website did not update new posts. I was digging too deep. I just needed to empty my server cache. Now everything works fine again. Thanks for your reply!